# What Options Do I Have to Build Latest VS 2017 Version of RestSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, restsharp

I would like to use RestSharp in a script task in SSIS.  Due to complications with SSIS script tasks, I would like to avoid acquiring it through it's NuGet package and would prefer to download and build the assembly myself.  However, my team has decided to use VS 2015 as our common development environment for the time being, and when I try to open the latest RestSharp solution, I get errors:

> error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild
>   XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Which, from some light Googling, seems to imply that VS 2017 is needed.  Is it absolutely required for me to have VS 2017 installed, or do I have any other options?

Comment: Why not simply download the NuGet package, rename it to .zip, and extract the assembly? In the lib directory you'll find assemblies for different frameworks; I'm assuming you want net452 or similar. I just did this in under a minute.

Comment: ... I didn't know I could do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the assembly then there's no need to worry about building the source. You can get the compiled assemblies from NuGet packages.

Find the RestSharp package in the NuGet gallery and download it.

[image]

Change the .nupkg extension to .zip and extract the archive to a directory.

[image]

Get the relevant assembly from the directories in the lib directory.

[image]